# Cannot access KnockoutJS variable from HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, data-binding

My variable patientObj is of the form:[image: patientObj]

patientObj has been created as:

```
function PAndD(date, ishidden, diagnosis, prescriptionObj)  {
    var self = this;
    self.date = date;
    self.ishidden = ishidden;
    self.diagnosis = diagnosis;
    self.prescriptionsRetrieved = ko.observableArray(prescriptionObj);
};

function Prescription(name, quantity, dosage, type)   {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.quantity = quantity;
    self.dosage = dosage;
    self.type = ko.observable(type);
};

function PatientData(name, sex, dob, height, weight, address)   {
    var self = this;
    self.name = name;
    self.sex = sex;
    self.dob = dob;
    self.height = height;
    self.weight = weight;
    self.address = address;
    self.pandd = ko.observableArray([]);
};

function doctorViewModel()    {
    var patientObj = new PatientData(x.name, x.sex, x.dob, x.height, x.weight, x.address);

    for(var i = 0; i < y.length; i++)   {
        var prescriptionObj = [];
        for(var j = 0; j < y[i].prescriptions.length; j++)  {
            prescriptionObj.push(new Prescription(y[i].prescriptions[j].name, y[i].prescriptions[j].quantity, y[i].prescriptions[j].dosage, y[i].prescriptions[j].type));
        }
        patientObj.pandd().push(new PAndD(y[i].date, y[i].ishidden, y[i].diagnosis, prescriptionObj));
    }

    self.patientObj(patientObj);
    console.log("patientList", self.patientObj());
    isPatientDataAvailable.isPatientDataAvailable(true);
}
```

I am trying to access the patientObj using KnockoutJS by dynamically adding a new division as:

```
var parent_div = document.getElementById('parent_div');
var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
newdiv.setAttribute('id','mydiv');
newdiv.innerHTML = "<p data-bind=\"text: $root.patientObj.name\"></p>";
parent_div.appendChild(newdiv);
```

But this doesn't show any output in HTML. What is the problem here?

HTML after creating dynamic element:

```
<div id="mydiv">
   <p data-bind="text: $root.patientObj.name"></p>
</div>
```

I even tried looking at the order at which the data is becoming available for access and it turns out that the dynamic division is trying to access it after it has loaded, so I don't understand what the problem is. Some help?

Comment: You should add a fiddle to show the behavior.  But I would suspect that you are going to need to re-apply bindings after you add an element with a binding like that.

Comment: @Timh That worked. I included the knockout.js and my patient.js after loading the entire page and worked. Had to tweak the flow of operation, of course. Thanks a ton! And sorry, I'm kind of new to javascript altogether, so didn't know much about jsfiddle. I'll try to edit my question with a link to jsfiddle. Thanks again!

Comment: sure, glad you got it to work! :D